# Effects of terrain on outdoor sound propagation?

Tags: acoustics, computational-physics

I'm looking for a computationally fast model for capturing the effects of varying terrain topology in far-field outdoor acoustic propagation, and was wondering if anyone had any insight or could point me in the right direction. I'm currently aware of [Rasmussen's](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022460X85904006) terrain profile methodology, as well as various [PE solvers](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221849496_Application_of_the_Beilis-Tappert_parabolic_equation_method_to_sound_propagation_over_irregular_terrain) for capturing these effects, but I was hoping for something much faster, even if it's just a really rough first-order model. Even if it's as simple as applying function weightings based on terrain gradient or something similar, that would be excellent.

Do any such models even exist? I'm greatly valuing speed over accuracy, so any low fidelity model would do.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: it seems as if ISO 9613 might be the best way to accomplish this. In it, an algebraic methodology for calculating ground attenuation based on average heights AGL from source to receiver is given. Comparisons of this methodology with measurements and more complex PE solvers can also be easily found in literature.